# NSFetchedResultsController is not updating continuously

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi I have moved from using `NSKeyedArchiver` to use `CoreData`

I was interested because of the `NSFetchedResultsController` class and its benefits with the `UITableView`.

my app is a download manager that has to update UITableViewCell continuously until it finishes downloading

Unfortunately after implementing this behavior my table view updates the data occasionally it happens like this I open my `UITableView` that has the the information about a particular download process sometimes it keeps updating, sometimes it updates a portion and sometimes it doesn't at all

But surely the download process is happening. here is my code.

The `NSFetchedResultsController` is implemented in a model class that is a *singleton*

```
    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<RCDownload> = {

    let request: NSFetchRequest<RCDownload> = RCDownload.fetchRequest()
    let sortDiscriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(RCDownload.startDate), ascending: false)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDiscriptor]
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: sharedCoreDataController.getContext(), sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("failed to fetch downloads")
    }

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

then the `UITableView` code is like this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    sharedDownloadController.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
}

    func configureCell(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RCDownloadTVCell else {
        return
    }
    let download = sharedDownloadController.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    let downloadState = download.descriptionAsState()
    let downloaded = Double(download.downloadedBytes) / 1000000
    let downloadSize = Double(download.fileSize) / 1000000
    if downloaded > 0 {
        cell.fileDescription.text = String(format: "%.1fMB of %.1fMB", downloaded, downloadSize)
    } else {
        cell.fileDescription.text = String("Loading...")
    }
    cell.fileName.text = download.fileName
    cell.progressView.setProgress(download.progressPercentage, animated: false)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        switch downloadState {
        case .downloading:
            cell.actionButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            cell.actionButton.setTitle("Pause", for: [])
        case .suspended:
            cell.actionButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            cell.actionButton.setTitle("Resume", for: [])
        case .cancelled:
            cell.actionButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
            cell.actionButton.setTitle("Resume", for: [])
        case .finished:
            cell.actionButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
            cell.actionButton.setTitle("Done", for: [])
        }
    }
}

extension RCDownloadsTVC: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }
}
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            guard let newIndexPath = newIndexPath else {
                fatalError()
            }
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .right)
            self.reloadData()
            break
        case .update:
            guard let indexPath = indexPath else {
                fatalError()
            }
            self.configureCell(tableView: self.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
            break
        case .move:

            break
        case .delete:
            guard let indexPath = indexPath else {
                fatalError()
            }
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

}

RCDownload is being updated using `URLSession` `didWriteData` method

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "taskIdentifier == %d", Int16(downloadTask.taskIdentifier) as CVarArg)
    let downloads = self.fetchDownloadsWith(predicate: predicate)
    if downloads.isEmpty != true {
        let download = downloads[0]
        if let fileName = downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename {
            download.fileName = fileName
        } else {
            download.fileName = downloadTask.response?.url?.lastPathComponent
        }
        download.fileSize = totalBytesExpectedToWrite
        download.downloadedBytes = totalBytesWritten
        download.progressPercentage = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    }
}
```

PS: please if any code is still needed just let me know to update.

Comment: Unrelated but never call `reloadData` right after `insertRows` and `deleteRows`. Both methods **do** update the UI. And break statements are not needed in Swift (except `.move`). And why do you `dispatch` **everything**?

Comment: I just corrected those and for dispatch i am just making sure that NSFetchedResultsController is updating on one thread as it was recommended by some devs, issue still there.

Comment: What process is updating the `RCDownload` objects?

Comment: updated my question to show that @pbasdf

Comment: What context is `fetchDownloadsWith` using?

Comment: the default, 'self.persistentContainer.viewContext'

Comment: Try adding .move also, and DONT move cells, just configureCell for indexPath and newIndexPath

Comment: Also you need to save when you update the downloadPercent, I dont think fetchResults would update unless you save?